# ExpReg para separar datos de una cadena

Tags: javascript, regex, aplicación-web

Necesito procesar una lista de ítems para separar algunos valores.

La cadena consta de un nombre y un valor numérico, los cuales debo almacenar en un `array_nombre` por un lado y `array_numeros` por otro. Para ello mi idea ha sido separar mediante expresiones regulares, sin embargo el resultado no es el que se espera.

Esto es lo que llevo:

```js
var nombreValor = document.getElementById("entrada").innerHTML;
var extraerNombres = nombreValor.split(/\d+.+/gm); //:: Array que almacena el nombre de cada item
extraerNombres.forEach(element => document.write('<div>-' + element + '-</div>'));
var extraerValor = nombreValor.match(/\d+/gm); //:: Array que almacena el costo de cada item
extraerValor.forEach(element => document.write('<div>-' + element + ' gp' + '-</div>'));
```

```html
<p id="entrada" style="display:none;">
    Icy War Axe 12 000 gp
    Jade Hammer 25 000 gp
    Krimhorn Helmet 200 gp
    Lavos Armor 16 000 gp
    Leaf Legs 500 gp
    Leopard Armor 1 000 gp
    Leviathan's Amulet 3 000 gp
    Light Shovel 300 gp
    Lightning Boots 2 500 gp
    Lightning Headband 2 500 gp
    Lightning Legs 11 000 gp
    Lightning Pendant 1 500 gp
    Lightning Robe 11 000 gp
    Lunar Staff 5 000 gp
    Magic Plate Armor 90 000 gp
    Magma Amulet 1 500 gp
    Magma Boots 2 500 gp
    Magma Coat 11 000 gp
    Magma Legs 11 000 gp
    Magma Monocle 2 500 gp
    Mammoth Fur Cape 6 000 gp
    Mammoth Fur Shorts 850 gp
    Mammoth Whopper 300 gp
    Mastermind Shield 50 000 gp
    Medusa Shield 9 000 gp
    Mercenary Sword 12 000 gp
    Model Ship 1 000 gp
    Mycological Bow 35 000 gp
    Mystic Blade 30 000 gp
    Naginata 2 000 gp
    Nightmare Blade 35 000 gp
    Noble Axe 10 000 gp
    Norse Shield 1 500 gp
    Onyx Pendant 3 500 gp
    Orcish Maul 6 000 gp
    Oriental Shoes 15 000 gp
    Pair of Iron Fists 4 000 gp
    Paladin Armor 15 000 gp
    Patched Boots 2 000 gp
    Pharaoh Banner 1 000 gp
    Pharaoh Sword 23 000 gp
    Pirate Boots 3 000 gp
    Pirate Hat 1 000 gp
    Pirate Knee Breeches 200 gp
    Pirate Shirt 500 gp
    Pirate Voodoo Doll 500 gp
    Platinum Amulet 2 500 gp
    Ragnir Helmet 400 gp
    Relic Sword 25 000 gp
    Rift Bow 45 000 gp
    Rift Crossbow 45 000 gp
    Rift Lance 30 000 gp
    Rift Shield 50 000 gp
    Ring of the Sky 30 000 gp
    Royal Axe 40 000 gp
    Ruby Necklace 2 000 gp
    Ruthless Axe 45 000 gp
    Sacred Tree Amulet 3 000 gp
    Sapphire Hammer 7 000 gp
    Scarab Amulet 200 gp
    Scarab Shield 2 000 gp
    Shockwave Amulet 3 000 gp
    Silver Brooch 150 gp
    Silver Dagger 500 gp
    Skull Helmet 40 000 gp
    Skullcracker Armor 18 000 gp
    Spiked Squelcher 5 000 gp
    Steel Boots 30 000 gp
    Swamplair Armor 16 000 gp
</p>
```

El resultado que busco es este:

- 1.- Quitar la palabra 'gp'
- 2.- Quitar el espacio entre los números
- 3.- Guardar el texto en un array
- 4.- Guardar los números en un array

  ```
  Un array_nombre = ['Icy War Axe','Jade Hammer','Krimhorn Helmet','n...']
  Y un array_numeros = ['12000','25000','200','n...']
  ```

Que luego usaré por separado para conformar una tabla.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando la estrategia divide y vencerás:

1. Buscamos nombres (letras y espacios).
2. Buscamos números (números con espacio en medio).
3. Quitamos los espacios en los números.

Es más sencillo a veces usar dos expresiones regulares que una compleja.

```js
let nombreValorList = document.getElementById("entrada").innerHTML.split(/\n/).filter(n => n);
const nombreRE = /[a-z ]+/i; //letras y espacios
const cantidadesRE = /[0-9]* ?[0-9]+/ //numeros
let nombres = nombreValorList.map(nv => {
  if (nv){
   const r= nv.match(nombreRE)[0].trim();
   return r
  }
});

let precios = nombreValorList.map(nv => {
  if (nv){
   const r= nv.match(cantidadesRE)[0].replace(/ /g,'');
   return r
  }
});




nombres.forEach(element => document.write('<div>-' + element + '-</div>'));

precios.forEach(element => document.write('<div>-' + element + ' gp' + '-</div>'));
```

```html
<p id="entrada" style="display:none;">
    Icy War Axe 12 000 gp
    Jade Hammer 25 000 gp
    Krimhorn Helmet 200 gp
    Lavos Armor 16 000 gp
    Leaf Legs 500 gp
    Leopard Armor 1 000 gp
    Leviathan's Amulet 3 000 gp
    Light Shovel 300 gp
    Lightning Boots 2 500 gp
    Lightning Headband 2 500 gp
    Lightning Legs 11 000 gp
    Lightning Pendant 1 500 gp
    Lightning Robe 11 000 gp
    Lunar Staff 5 000 gp
    Magic Plate Armor 90 000 gp
    Magma Amulet 1 500 gp
    Magma Boots 2 500 gp
    Magma Coat 11 000 gp
    Magma Legs 11 000 gp
    Magma Monocle 2 500 gp
    Mammoth Fur Cape 6 000 gp
    Mammoth Fur Shorts 850 gp
    Mammoth Whopper 300 gp
    Mastermind Shield 50 000 gp
    Medusa Shield 9 000 gp
    Mercenary Sword 12 000 gp
    Model Ship 1 000 gp
    Mycological Bow 35 000 gp
    Mystic Blade 30 000 gp
    Naginata 2 000 gp
    Nightmare Blade 35 000 gp
    Noble Axe 10 000 gp
    Norse Shield 1 500 gp
    Onyx Pendant 3 500 gp
    Orcish Maul 6 000 gp
    Oriental Shoes 15 000 gp
    Pair of Iron Fists 4 000 gp
    Paladin Armor 15 000 gp
    Patched Boots 2 000 gp
    Pharaoh Banner 1 000 gp
    Pharaoh Sword 23 000 gp
    Pirate Boots 3 000 gp
    Pirate Hat 1 000 gp
    Pirate Knee Breeches 200 gp
    Pirate Shirt 500 gp
    Pirate Voodoo Doll 500 gp
    Platinum Amulet 2 500 gp
    Ragnir Helmet 400 gp
    Relic Sword 25 000 gp
    Rift Bow 45 000 gp
    Rift Crossbow 45 000 gp
    Rift Lance 30 000 gp
    Rift Shield 50 000 gp
    Ring of the Sky 30 000 gp
    Royal Axe 40 000 gp
    Ruby Necklace 2 000 gp
    Ruthless Axe 45 000 gp
    Sacred Tree Amulet 3 000 gp
    Sapphire Hammer 7 000 gp
    Scarab Amulet 200 gp
    Scarab Shield 2 000 gp
    Shockwave Amulet 3 000 gp
    Silver Brooch 150 gp
    Silver Dagger 500 gp
    Skull Helmet 40 000 gp
    Skullcracker Armor 18 000 gp
    Spiked Squelcher 5 000 gp
    Steel Boots 30 000 gp
    Swamplair Armor 16 000 gp
</p>
```